# Generate a compiler warning for enum.ordinal

Tags: java, enums, static-analysis

Working Java 7+ .... Suppose we create an enum:

```
enum Foo{ FOO, BAR }
```

then `Foo.FOO.ordinal() == 0`.  However, if I reorder the enum, say:

```
enum Foo{ BAR, FOO }
```

then `Foo.FOO.ordinal() == 1`. This is surprising for most people, as they feel reordering fields is a "safe" operation. No surprise that Java recommends *against* using `enum.ordinal()` in most cases.  There are plenty of alternatives, most obviously (and self-documentingly) associating each enum value with an int.

Unfortunately some people in my company did not get the memo and a lot of our old code uses the `.ordinal()` method all over the place, depending in a fundamental way on the association between the int and the enum value. When I have time, I go through and refactor, but it doesn't prevent new code from using `.ordinal()`, which introduces potentially untraceable bugs.

So! Suppose I have an enum with a lot of structure associated to it. Can I somehow mark the `.ordinal()` as *unsafe*, so that if someone uses (say) `Foo.FOO.ordinal()` a compiler warning will be generated?

I'm content to use external packages for this purpose but would prefer it if they weren't too obscure.

Comment: I have never done this, so take it with a grain of salt; but I would look into a quality tool like PMD and write a custom rule.

Comment: What is your setup? Do you have some CI environment? We for example prevent usage of the @Inject-Annotation from guice via some kind of maven plugin rule set. Do you want some warning in the IDE or a git commit hook or on the CI system?

Comment: Too bad it's `final`, otherwise you could override the method and deprecate it.

Comment: @luk2302 We're using IntelliJ, and I'd prefer to get the warning there, rather than in Jenkins or etc.

Comment: One solution could be to use some static analysis tool. You can write custom rules with SonarQube or PMD (and many others) and integrate those tools into your development process. Disclaimer - I work on Java analyzer for SonarQube

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of an `enum` is to decouple the code from the underlying value, and using `ordinal()` defeats the purpose.

You didn't say, but I suspect the problem occurs at the interface between the Java code and external storage, i.e. using `ordinal()` to "serialize" the enum into something you can store in a file or database.

I think you're out of luck here.  As @Henry says, your only option is likely to be a code analysis tool with a custom rule to flag all usages of `ordinal()`, and a massive refactoring effort to accomplish four tasks:

1. Modify every enum declaration to immutably and permanently attach an integer value, independent of `ordinal()` to every enum value.
2. To every enum declaration, add a method `int toInteger()` that returns the integer value.
3. To every enum declaration, add a method `static EnumClassName fromInteger(int v)` to "deserialize" the external value
4. Refactor all references to `ordinal()` to use the new `toInteger()` and `fromInteger()` methods.

Comment: Well, you've correctly understood the problem. I'll hold off accepting for a while to see if someone comes up with a clever solution to "enforcing" (4) from your list.

Answer (score 0):

How about this XPath PMD rule?

//PrimaryPrefix/Name[ends-with(@Image, '.ordinal')]

Just put it in a ruleset XML file in a rule element something like this:

```
<rule name="DontUseEnumOrdinal" message="Please no enums ordinal"
    class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule" language="java">
    <description>We don't take kindly enum ordinal() round these parts</description>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
        <property name="xpath">
            <value><![CDATA[//PrimaryPrefix/Name[ends-with(@Image, '.ordinal')]]]></value>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <example><![CDATA[MyEnum.MY_VALUE.ordinal(); //is bad
        MyEnum.MY_VALUE.index(); //is better]]>
    </example>
</rule>
```